# What does it mean to find an efficient algorithm for NP complete problems

Tags: algorithms, np

Suppose I have a problem $P$, an instance $I$ and an algorithm $A$ that efficently solves $P$ for $I$.
Let $P'$ be $P$ with additional constraints that are violated if $A$ is applied to $I$ and finding the solution for $P'$ on $I$ is NP-complete.

Assume now that it were possible to transform $I$ to $I'$ with the property that applying $A$ to $I'$ would solve $P$ for $I'$ however not $P'$ for $I'$ *but* the solution of $P'$ for $I$ can be efficiently determined from the solution of $P$ for $I'$, thus proving $P=NP$.

**Question:**

- would it be justified to say that $A$ is an efficient algorithm for solving $P'$ problems?
- would such scenario explain why the search for algorithms that efficiently solve NP-complete problem instances is invane because they already exist but their potential when combined with the right transformation of problem instances isn't recognized?

My apologies if the question should be too esoteric for MO.

Comment: If anything, it is in some ways 'too straightforward' for MO, which is for research-level problems; I'd suggest asking it on either math.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: What does "Let $P'$ be $P$ with additional constraints that are violated if $A$ is applied to $I$ and finding the solution for $P'$ on $I$ is NP-complete" mean exactly? In what sense is a problem allowed to place constraints on the algorithms which are "allowed" to solve it?

Comment: @NoahSchweber $P$ could be the cycle cover of an undirected graph and $P'$ a connected cycle cover aka Hamilton cycle. $P'$ doesn't impose constraints on $A$ but on the "acceptable" solutions generated by $A$.

Comment: "*finding the solution for P′ on I is NP-complete*" is a category error. A problem can be NP-complete, but an instance cannot.